# Is it possible to prevent Windows from trying to create thumbnails of files inside CD/DVD?

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive

Every time I open a CD/DVD in explorer I have to wait for Windows to create all the files thumbnails before I can do anything else. I suppose it's due to the fact that it tries to access all files concurrently and this kills performances since optical drives are very bad at anything that's not sequential reading.

Is it possible to disable thumbnails only for CD/DVD?

Comment: How about simply switching to Details view for that drive?

Comment: @Karan I've tried but no matter what view I use, Windows create them anyway. I'm quite sure the performance problem is caused by the creation of the previews because if I insert a DVD with just .mkv files (Windows can't create previews of such files), the problem dose not appear.

Comment: I don't get it. By "previews" you're talking about thumbnails, right? I suggested Details view precisely because it doesn't use thumbnails. Can you see if selecting the `Tools menu > Folder options > View tab > Always show icons, never thumbnails` option in Win Explorer helps?

Comment: @Karan yes I meant thumbnails sorry, (I'll edit the question), anyway, disabling them all together as you described almost fixed the performance problem. There's still some hidden activity going on that keeps the disk busy but it lasts for far less than before. Is there a way to have thumbnails disabled only for specific places? (e.g. the optical drive)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible.